# Header Predicate in Apache Camel

Tags: java, api, apache-camel, predicate

After first misspelling i wanted typed support for my predicate expression. So turned to

```
header(Exchange.FILE_NAME)
```

as in ...

```
from("file://src/test/resources/routingtodifferentdestinations-source?noop=true")//
.choice()//
.when(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).contains("widget.txt"))//
```

(Q) Where/How happens the distinction between "header.in" and "header.out" in that API.

The equivalent case written in simple, where the distinction is made between in.header and out.header is made explicit:

```
simple("${in.header.CamelFileName} contains 'widget.txt'"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to concern about IN vs OUT really. Just use IN always. Or better yet do not use in at all, as that is implied, eg ${in.headers.foo} is the same as ${headers.foo}.

See this FAQ
http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html